# Why does atom's node version differ from apm's node version?

Tags: node.js, electron, atom-editor

I feel like this is causing my atom packages (terminal-plus) node-gyp problems (version mismatch expected xx, got xx)

```
$ atom -v
Atom    : 1.11.0
Electron: 0.37.8
Chrome  : 49.0.2623.75
Node    : 5.10.0

$ apm -v
apm  1.12.5
npm  3.10.5
node 4.4.5
python 2.7.12
git 2.10.0
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 0):

Electron has it's own embedded version of Node that's distinct from whatever Node version you have installed on your system. `atom -v` displays Node version in Electron, while `apm -v` probably just displays the Node version you've installed. This is why native Node modules have to be rebuilt to target the specific version of Electron they're used in.